# C++ Dynamically allocate a structure which contains an union[vec or map] twice leads to a bad_alloc error

Tags: c++, struct, tree, unions

I have a bunch of tuples `(int array[N], string message)` to store. I want to be able to add/delete a lot of elements from this array very quickly but, most importantly, given another array `array2`, I want to find every string such that for all `i` : `array[i] <= array2[i]` (not implemented yet).

Thus, I thought about using a tree of height N where a leaf is a message. If it is a leaf, it should contain a vector if it's a node, it should contain a map.

I am using an union to manage whether a tree is a leaf or a node.

My delete function should delete the leaf and all the nodes that lead only to this leaf.

I can insert a message (or multiple different messages). However, I can't reinsert a message that I previously deleted. It raises a `bad_alloc` error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    enum{LEAF, NODE} tag;
    union {
        std::map<int, struct Node*> map;
        std::vector<std::string> msg;
    };
    Node(std::string m){
        tag = LEAF;
        cout << "Flag 1 : Crashing here, for some reasons a map is allocated" << "\n";
        msg.push_back(m);
        cout << "Flag 2 : Did you manage to fix it ?" << "\n";
    }
    Node(){
        tag = NODE;
        map = std::map<int, struct Node*>();
    }
    ~Node(){
        if (tag==NODE){
            map.~map();
        } else {
            msg.~vector();
        }
    }
};

void insert(int* array, int size, Node* node, std::string msg){
    cout << "Insert\n";
    if (size > 1){
        if (!node -> map.count(array[0])){
            node->map[array[0]] = new Node();
        }
        insert(array+1, size-1, node->map[array[0]], msg);
    } else {
        if (!node->map.count(array[0])){
            cout << "Case 1\n";
            node -> map[array[0]] = new Node(msg);
        }
        else{
            cout << "Case 2\n";
            node -> map[array[0]]->msg.push_back(msg);
        }
    }
}

bool find(int * array, int size, Node * node){
    if (!node -> map.count(array[0])){
        return false;
    }
    if (size==1){
        return true;
    }
    return find(array+1, size-1, node->map[array[0]]);
    
}

std::vector<std::string> find_vec(int * array, int size, Node * node){
    if (!node -> map.count(array[0])){
        return std::vector<std::string>();
    }
    if (size==1){
        if (!node -> map.count(array[0])){
            return std::vector<std::string>();
        }
        return node -> map[array[0]]->msg;
    }
    return find_vec(array+1, size-1, node->map[array[0]]);
}

void print_array(std::vector<std::string> v){
    for (auto & elem : v){
        cout << elem << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void erase(int * array, int size, Node * node){
    std::vector<Node*> vec;
    int i = 0;
    Node *t = node;
    while (i < size){
        if (t -> map.count(array[i])){
            vec.push_back(t);
            t = t-> map[array[i]];
        } else 
            break;
        i++;
    }

    
    if (i == size){
        
        // Deleting the leaf 
        cout << "Deleting Leaf\n";
        delete t; 
        
        cout << "Deleting vec [" << size-1 << "] elem " << array[size-1] << "\n";
        cout << "Deleted ? " << vec[size-1]->map.erase(array[size-1]) << "\n";
        
        // Deleting the path if it has no other leaf
        cout << "Delete Path\n";
        for (i = size-1; i > 0; i--){
            //cout << "debut loop " << i << "\n";
            //vec[i-1]->map.erase(array[i-1]);
            if (!vec[i] -> map.size()){
                delete vec[i];
                cout << "Deleting vec [" << i-1 << "] elem " << array[i-1] << "\n";
                cout << "Deleted ? " << vec[i-1]->map.erase(array[i-1]) << "\n";
            }
            else 
                break;
            //cout << "fin loop\n";
        }
    }
    
}


int main()
{
    Node * Tree = new Node;
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
        cout << "k = " << k << "\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        
        int size = 4;
        int array[4] = {0,1,2,3};
        
        
        std::string m1 = "Random message that I want to store as many times as I want";
        
        insert(array, size, Tree, m1);
        
        
        cout << "find : " << find(array, size, Tree) << "\n";
        
        
        std::vector<std::string> vec1 = find_vec(array, size, Tree);
        
        
        cout << "vec "; 
        print_array(vec1);
       
    
    
        cout << "-------------------\n";
        erase(array, size, Tree);
        cout << "We should find the message \n";
        print_array(vec1);
        
        cout << "-------------------\n";
        cout << "We should not find the message \n";
        vec1 = find_vec(array, size, Tree);
        print_array(vec1);
        cout << "-------------------\n";
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question actually is?

Comment: My code is crashing. 
Once I insert a message, delete it and reinsert it, the second insertion raises a bad alloc error. I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

A `union` should be treated with care, especially when used with non-trivial members like in your example. Specifically of interest is this [passage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) from cppreference:

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial
> special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment,
> or destructor), that function is deleted by default in the union and
> needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.
>
> If a union contains a non-static data member with a **non-trivial
> default constructor**, the default constructor of the union is deleted
> by default unless a variant member of the union has a default member
> initializer .

The map member is not constructed and therefore you cannot just start using it.

I recommend using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) as a safe alternative to a raw union. Your example would look like the following without a need for your `enum`:

```
struct Node {
    std::variant<std::map<int, Node*>, std::vector<std::string>> data;

    Node(std::string m){
        data.emplace<1>();
        cout << "Flag 1 : Crashing here, for some reasons a map is allocated" << "\n";
        std::get<1>(data).push_back(m);
        cout << "Flag 2 : Did you manage to fix it ?" << "\n";
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: It fixed my problem thank you. I would like to know if std::variant<class1, class2> would require me to modify the default destructor

Comment: @user_name01910191 The default ctor of map and vector you cannot modify. Your Node default ctor, you can modify according to the example I gave you for `Node(std::string)`. Checking which type is currently active, you can do with `holds_alternative` -- check out the documentation I linked to.